# Symfony2 OneToMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Related to my previous post :

[Symfony2 OneToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997783/symfony2-onetomany-relation)

I wanna add this feature to my infoAction(); who list all the adverts.

```
    public function infoAction()
{
    $listAdverts = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('SocietyPerfclientBundle:Advert')
        ->getAdverts()
    ;

    return $this->render('SocietyPerfclientBundle:Default:info.html.twig', array(
        'listAdverts' => $listAdverts,
    ));
}
```

What i have to do here to access in my view :

`{% for reader in advert.readers %}
    <i>Seen by : {{ reader.username }}</i>
 {% endfor %}`

Comment: which is your error?problem? regards

Comment: I dont know how to do.. have a look at my link please :)

Comment: Have you implemented the getAdverts method on repository? You can use finBy (advertId) or if you want all adverts use findAll(). It will give you an array.
And use listAdverts.readers in your loop. 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all, regarding your first link (which, from now on, you should post all the problems/question in one single post, and not creating multiple ones, and if you have something to add/remove, you can edit your post), you are not setting the relation correctly:

In class `Advert` you are missing some essential methods. For that, run

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities SocietyPerfclientBundle:Advert
```

to let doctrine generate the missing methods for you. Same for `AdvertReader` entity.

At the end, you have to have the instantiation for `$readers` field in `Advert` entity. Something like:

```
$this->readers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

And as well as these methods: `addReader(AdvertReader $reader)`, `removeReader(AdvertReader $reader)`, and `getReaders()`.

In `AdvertReader` entity, you only have to have `setAdvert(Advert $advers)` and `getAdvert()`.

Give it a try and let us know if worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You give to your template $listAdvert whose contains your advert data.
In order to display it in your view you have to use it not directly the name of your Entity

```php
{% for reader in listAdverts.readers %}
    <i>Seen by : {{ reader.username }}</i>
 {% endfor %}
```

Fixing Controller

```php
$listAdverts = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('SocietyPerfclientBundle:Advert')
        ->findAll()
    ;
```

Comment: Twig error : Key "readers" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" does not exist in SocietyPerfclientBundle:Default:info.html.twig

Comment: You don't send back weel the Entity. Fix this in your controller